# "Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem" even though versions do not conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

`Bundle install` complains that it can't find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer," even though the dependency constraints it shows in the error do not conflict.

It gives me this output running `bundle install` which I'm so stumped by

```
  In Gemfile:
    premailer-rails was resolved to 1.10.3, which depends on
      actionmailer (>= 3)

    rails (> 3.0, < 3.2.22.1) was resolved to 3.2.22, which depends on
      actionmailer (= 3.2.22)
```

The dependencies appear to not conflict at all.

I have tried explicitly setting rails to '3', instead of 3.2.22.1, which seems to remove the error. But isn't 3.x.x.x equal to >3 ?

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '<3.2.22.1', '>3.0'
gem 'premailer-rails'
... #other gems
```

The output shows it resolves rails to 3.2.22, and that actionmailer >=3 is a dependency for premailer-rails, and actionmailer = 3.2.22 is a dependency for rails.

All constraints are met. 3.2.22 is >=3, and the dependency should resolve. What am I missing?

Comment: what bundler version do you have installed?

Comment: version = 1.17.3

Comment: I also have the same issue with actionpack etc.

Answer (score -1):

Did you install more recent Rails in this directory before? In this case bundler remembers its dependent `actionmailer` version and now this more recent `actionmailer` prevents installing the older one. Because `install` action in fact does [conservative updating](https://bundler.io/v1.17/man/bundle-install.1.html#CONSERVATIVE-UPDATING), analyzing only changes between last `Gemfile.lock` and current `Gemfile`.

Anyway, remove `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again.